# Ionic 3 grid doesn't center vertically rows items

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, sass, ionic3

Ionic component Grid not sure why it doesn't center them. i have tried their official documentation for [vertical alignment](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/grid/Grid/#vertical-alignment) still doesn't work.
please let me know if any other detail is needed.

```
<ion-content>

   <ion-row justify-content-center align-items-center>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label stacked color="primary">Username</ion-label>
        <ion-input [(ngModel)]="login.username" name="username" type="text" #username="ngModel" spellcheck="false" autocapitalize="off"
          required>
        </ion-input>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row justify-content-center align-items-center>

      <ion-item>
        <ion-label stacked color="primary">Password</ion-label>
        <ion-input [(ngModel)]="login.password" name="password" type="password" #password="ngModel" required>
        </ion-input>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-row>

  </ion-grid>

</ion-content>
```

[image]

Result what i need[image]

Comment: Can you show the final UI where you want? i.e. Image of it.

Comment: I want those two input to be vertically center. means they should have equal width space from top and bottom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done it using `flex` as shown below.

Working [**stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-7rdhra?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.scss)

*html*

```
<ion-content padding class="sign-in">
    <ion-grid>
        <ion-row class="row1">
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row class="row2">
            <ion-col col-12>
                <ion-item>
                    <ion-label stacked color="primary">Username</ion-label>
                    <ion-input [(ngModel)]="login.username" name="username" type="text">
                    </ion-input>
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item>
                    <ion-label stacked color="primary">Password</ion-label>
                    <ion-input [(ngModel)]="login.password" name="password" type="password">
                    </ion-input>
                </ion-item>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>

</ion-content>
```

*.scss*

```
  .sign-in {
        ion-grid {
            min-height: 100%;
        }
        .row1 {
            flex: 1;
        }
        .row2 {
            flex: 1;
        }
     }
```

*UI*

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer but just to ask why their css utility didn't work as per their documentation..i can use this just want to know why documentation justify-content-center align-items-center didn't work..

Comment: It is for a different purpose. It says `All columns can be vertically aligned inside of a row`. So you can see that it does `inside the row`.But you need outside the row. You can play here using different attributes.Then you'll realize it. https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-phy7tt?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html

Comment: Quick question again flex property defines the length not height...then how this is working..

Comment: The `flex` property defines how much of the available space the element should take up.You can learn more about it here: https://www.joshmorony.com/an-in-depth-look-at-the-grid-system-in-ionic-2/

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp as per this document flex property defines length? is it possible that Ionic is doing something different as compare to standard just asking

Comment: No.`The Flexbox Layout officially called CSS Flexible Box Layout Module is new layout module in CSS3 made to improve the items align, directions and order in the container even when they are with dynamic or even unknown size`.  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/